# gunzip wait for wget

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, pipeline

Goal: I want to download some gz files and decompress them with the default file names in a for loop.

E.G., download [`pageviews-20200601-000000.gz`](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2020/2020-06/pageviews-20200601-000000.gz) and decompress it to get `pageviews-20200601-000000` (this is the default file name).

I tried `wget https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2020/2020-06/pageviews-20200601-000000.gz | gunzip -d`, but `gunzip` won't wait for `wget` to finish.

Is it possible to achieve the goal with pipeline? Or I have to introduce some variables?

Comment: `Is it possible to achieve the goal with pipeline?` You have to be more speicifc. `some gz files` Which one? `the default file names` What default filename? `somelink` What link? Please create an [MCVE]. Please post for example an array of links and the resulting commands to be executed and resulting filenames to be created as a result of the script. Please post your attempt.

Comment: @KamilCuk thx for reminding. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you making things too difficult here? What about this (just put it on two lines instead of one):

```
wget https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2020/2020-06/pageviews-20200601-000000.gz
gunzip -d pageviews-20200601-000000.gz
```

The second command is only executed when the first one is finished. Isn't that what you are looking for?